# Stringify a recursive `std::vector<std::vector<...>>` without using partial template function specialization

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, template-specialization, function-templates

I seek (for example) to stringify a vector of vectors of ... (with arbitrarily deep nesting).

I tried the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

template<typename E>
std::string toString(const E& element) {
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << element;
    return oss.str();
}

template<typename E>
std::string toString<std::vector<E>>(const std::vector<E>& set) {
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << "{";
    bool started = false;
    for (const auto& el : set) {
        if (started) {
            oss << ",";
        }
        else {
            started = true;
        }
        oss << toString(el);
    }
    oss << "}";
    return oss.str();
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<std::vector<int>> v{{1},{2,3}};
  std::cout << toString(v) << std::endl; // want to output "{{1},{2,3}}"
  return 0;
}
```

but it [generates a compiler](http://cpp.sh/9kron) error since partial template function specialization is apparently not allowed. How am I supposed to do this kind of thing then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want here is not template specialization but function overloading.

Use this instead of your template specialization method.

```
template <typename E>
std::string toString(const std::vector<E>& set) {
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << "{";
    bool started = false;
    for (const auto& el : set) {
        if (started) {
            oss << ",";
        }
        else {
            started = true;
        }
        oss << toString(el);
    }
    oss << "}";
    return oss.str();
}
```

Your code also has a typo: `oss << toSring(el)`.